# node js await buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am adding data to buffer with getOdds

```
getOdds = async(data) => {
    send({"Command":"GetMatchMarkets","Params":data});
    var message = JSON.stringify({"Command":"GetMatchMarkets","Params":data});
    var length = Buffer.byteLength(message),
    buffer = new Buffer(4 + Buffer.byteLength(message));
    buffer.writeUInt32LE(length, 0);
    buffer.write(message, 4);
    client.write(buffer);
    I WANT TO GET DATA FROM receiveCB getOdds
}
```

Read data with receiveBuff.
after.
I'm sending to receiveCB

```
function receiveBuff (buf) {
    var offset = 0;
    if (bytesToReceive === 0) { 
        if(buf.length < 4){ return; } 
        bytesToReceive = buf.readUInt32LE(0);
        offset = 4;
    }
    var currentCommandBytes = Math.min(bytesToReceive, buf.length - offset);
    receivedData += buf.slice(offset, offset + currentCommandBytes);
    bytesToReceive -= currentCommandBytes;
    if (bytesToReceive === 0) { 
        bytesToReceive = 0;

        receiveCB(JSON.parse(receivedData)); 
        receivedData = "";
    }
    if (currentCommandBytes < buf.length - offset) {  
        receiveBuff(buf.slice(currentCommandBytes+offset))
    }
}
```

```
receiveCB = async(response) => {
     return response;
}
```

I want to get data from receiveCB getOdds

[Please Click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXetx.png)

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you want to do?
You seem to be confusing a natural flow on execution since you are creating async functions that do not run async code.
You have to keep in mind that making a function as async won't make it work as a thread if it does not execute any real asynchronous operation it is not useful to do it so.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXetx.png

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**